# Search function that looks within my previously created controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search

I think this is a simple question but I couldn't find it.
I've been following [this guide](https://melvinchng.github.io/rails/SearchFeature.html) to make a search function. The tutorial actually uses SQL and I'm using PostgreSQL, but I don't think that makes any difference.

Instead of looking for `name` in `Store` database, I want it to search for `Plant_ID` in my `PlantTable` database.

This is what the tutorial showed:

```rb
#app/controllers/page_controller.rb 

  def index
  end
  def search  
    if params[:search].blank?  
      redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Empty field!") and return  
    else  
      @parameter = params[:search].downcase  
      @results = Store.all.where("lower(name) LIKE :search", search: @parameter)  
    end  
  end
end
```

But I actually added it into my home controller
and this was my final attempt

```rb
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def search
    @plant_tables = PlantTable.all
    #So I can get PlantTable from a different controller  
    if params[:search].blank?  
      redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Empty field!") and return  
    else  
      @parameter = params[:search].downcase  
      @results = @plant_tables.all.where("Plant_ID LIKE :search", search: @parameter)
      #I removed lower() because my Plant_ID is written like this.  
    end  
  end
end
```

Added code to my `routes.rb`:
`get '/search' => 'pages#search', :as => 'search_page'`

But in my `app/views/home/search.html.erb`...

```html
<h3>Search Result</h3>  

    <% @results.each do |result| %>  
        <%= result.name %><br>  
    <% end %>
```

...I get the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Home#search`

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "plant_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT "plant_tables".* FROM "plant_tables" WHERE (Plant_ID L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "plant_tables.Plant_ID".
```

Comment: Try prepending the table name (`plant_tables.Plant_ID ...`), what Rails version are you using? Is the column name really named `Plant_ID`, which such an interesting case? If the column is an integer, you're going to need an explicit cast.

Comment: It failed. I'm using Rails 6. The column name is Plant_ID because it was requested as such - it takes info from a CSV file with the same column name. It is a string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the particular case in which your column name is you'll have to wrap it in quotes and cast it to text to perform a LIKE query:

```
PlantTable.where('"Plant_ID" LIKE ?', @parameter)
```

Notice;

- Wrapping the column name in single quotes and the argument for `where` will not work.
- You can remove the second `all` you're chaining on `@results`.